# A voltage regulator that is controlling a voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, telephone

My scenario is that I am having a circuit which having 12V as the input voltage and works beween 8V to 15V. I want to limit this circuit in a way that if the input voltage drops below 12V criuit breaks from the input voltage and if voltage goes above 12V circuit invokes and get connected.

Plz Help.

Comment: You are looking for what is called an "Undervoltage Lockout" or "Undervoltage Cutoff". In your case, if the voltage is less than 12V you want the circuit to cut out or disconnect.  See this answer here for some guidance http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/4967/circuit-to-protect-against-undervoltage That answer is for < 3.3V lockout but the circuit designs are equivalent with minor changes to component values to get a different 12V lockout voltage that you need.

Comment: What about the tag "telephone" ??? "Plz Help" so why not accept the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try the LT3686 voltage regulator for size: -

[image]

The UVLO pin can be set with two resistors from the incoming power voltage so that below a certain input voltage, the output is switched off. There are plenty of switching voltage regulators that have this feature and quite a few linear ones too although this feature is mainly reserved for switchers.